# Compare entire array lines for a set of variables

Tags: c, arrays, if-statement

What i am trying to do is simple: i want to compare an entire line of an array in search of a set of variables in order like this:

`var[2][]=={1,2,3,4,5} //all at the same time`

instead of

`var[2][0]==1 && var[2][1]==2 && var[2][2]==3 && var[2][3]==4 && var[2][4]==5 //one by one`

or maybe

`vartwo[4][3...7]==var[2][] ou vartwo[4][]==var[2][]`

```
void main() {
    int i,var[5];
    puts("enter values:");

    for(;i<5;i++) {
        scanf("%d",&var[i]);
    };

    if(var[]=={1,1,1,0,0,0}) {
        //do stuff
    } else if (var[]=={1,2,3,5,2}) {
        //do something else
    }
    .
    .
    .
    } else {
        //not found
    }
}
```

is there any way i can do that?

Comment: Having aspirations is a noble thing. Note that you have not actually asked any question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to break but there is no way you can compare two arrays like the way you showed in `C`.

Simple old looping with element wise comparison is the way out.

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < len ;  i++)
  if( arr[i] == anotherarr[i] )
   // same
```

`memcmp` is an option but unless you can ensure there will be no padding you can't use it reliably.